# How to config JMS setting for using the same sent/received queue?

Tags: jms, soapui, web-api-testing

I want to use Soapui to test JMS webservice, and we use the same queue for sent/receive queues like this:

jms://SmartOTP_EMS::**queue_vn.smartotp_gw.1.0**::**queue_vn.smartotp_gw.1.0**

But there is a problem: The respone window always show request message, and I didn't get the response content correctly.

Do you know how to fix this in (we don't want to use different queues for destinations) ?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion , this would never work as SoapUI is not intelligent enough to differentiate between various responses in JMS . It will simple pick message from response queue and show on right side pane.

You need to write groovy script to connect to JMS and then pick your message based on message id.